External luks encrypted hard drive is mounted but sometimes no longer shows on lsblk?
I have an old linux laptop being used as a home server. It runs a bunch of docker containers basically. I have an external luks encrypted hard drive connected to the laptop which is mounted and luks is opened with a script. The docker containers use a docker mount to the same mounted location so that essentially files are saved to my external hard drive from my docker containers.
I decrypt and open / mount the drive like so:
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file=$KEY_FILE UUID=$DRIVE_UUID $PARTITION_NAME
sudo mount /dev/mapper/$PARTITION_NAME /mnt/storage

The result of lsblk -o NAME,KNAME,UUID,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE shows below.
 sdc                         sdc                                                      disk                     10.9T
 |-sdc1                      sdc1  67E3-17ED                              vfat        part                      200M
 |-sdc2                      sdc2  91c4ccef-ebf2-4976-8c93-93d48340022b   apfs        part                    465.7G
 `-sdc3                      sdc3  0d8b7631-030b-4e29-9eb4-079566c114a6   crypto_LUKS part                     10.5T
  `-seagate-external-hd-123 dm-2  f21491cc-ce4e-420d-8a76-585ea5fd57ab   ext4        crypt /mnt/storage       10.5T

However after a long while (few days to maybe couple weeks?) I notice in my logs that the result of the same lsblk command now shows:
 sdc                         sdc                                                      disk                     10.9T                                                                       
 |-sdc1                      sdc1  67E3-17ED                              vfat        part                      200M                                                                       
 |-sdc2                      sdc2  91c4ccef-ebf2-4976-8c93-93d48340022b   apfs        part                    465.7G                                                                     
 `-sdc3                      sdc3  0d8b7631-030b-4e29-9eb4-079566c114a6   crypto_LUKS part                     10.5T  

However when running ls -lah /mnt/storage I do in fact see the data in the hard drive. What's going on? Why does lsblk no longer show the mount point? Will writing to that mount point still make it to my  hard drive?
Also, what's the proper way to determine that an encrypted hard drive is open and mounted if I can't just use lsblk?
My script is run on a cron job because for some reason, after some extended period, the external hard drive mount would get unmounted. If the script detects that it tries to luksopen and mount. However the script was detecting whether luks was open based on seeing the $LUKS_UUID in lsblk command and now it seems that is not a reliable way to detect the drive is open. What is the proper way to determine if I can access it? Is it as simple as just checking df -h | grep /mnt/storage ? It's not clear to me if that is enough to say the drive is actually open / unencrypted / usable so I was originally using the lsblk command.
